# Error Accessing Member string::empty When Using Iterator

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I've been reading text material to hone my C++ skills and am having trouble with my iterator-string experiment. What I want to do is take a string, iterate through each element in the string, and output each element in the string. However, since I am learning how to use the arrow operator, the compiler is telling me I cannot access the member string::empty. Doesn't the variable aIter have type string::iterator?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sString("some string!");
    for(auto aIter = sString.cbegin();
        aIter != sString.cend() && !aIter->empty();
        aIter++)
        cout << *aIter << endl;

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

Error:
request for member 'empty' in '* aIter.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,    _Container>::operator-><const char*, std::basic_string<char> >()', which is of non-class type 'const char'|
```

Comment: The iterator "points" to characters, not strings. *which is of non-class type 'const char'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the characters of a string. Characters don't have member functions, and have no concept of being "empty".

You probably want to simply remove the `!aIter->empty()` test, to iterate until you reach the end of the string. This will work even if the string is empty: the `cbegin()` iterator will equal the `cend()` iterator, so the loop will end immediately.

If you wanted to check whether the string is empty (which you don't need to do here), that would be `sString.empty()`.

Comment: Ahh! Of course! Thank you! I assumed since it was a string, there wouldn't be a problem. Lesson learned.